'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element
I am getting error in my code. This is first time I am using React, previously I ran the code and it just run fine:
src/components/ResponseLengthButtonGroup/ResponseLengthButtonGroup.tsx:22:18 - error TS2786: 'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.

22                 <Button id="Thorough" className={`${defaultValue == 3072? styles.buttonrightactive : styles.buttonright ?? ""}`} size="sm" value={3072} bsPrefix='ia'>{"Thorough"}</Button>
                    ~~~~~~

This is ResponseLengthButtonGroup where I am getting this error:
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Label } from "@fluentui/react";

import styles from "./ResponseLengthButtonGroup.module.css";

interface Props {
    className?: string;
    onClick: (_ev: any) => void;
    defaultValue?: number;
}

export const ResponseLengthButtonGroup = ({ className, onClick, defaultValue }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.container} ${className ?? ""}`}>
            <Label>Response length:</Label>
            <ButtonGroup className={`${styles.buttongroup ?? ""}`} onClick={onClick}>
                <Button id="Succinct" className={`${defaultValue == 1024? styles.buttonleftactive : styles.buttonleft ?? ""}`} size="sm" value={1024} bsPrefix='ia'>{"Succinct"}</Button>
                <Button id="Standard" className={`${defaultValue == 2048? styles.buttonmiddleactive : styles.buttonmiddle ?? ""}`} size="sm" value={2048} bsPrefix='ia'>{"Standard"}</Button>
                <Button id="Thorough" className={`${defaultValue == 3072? styles.buttonrightactive : styles.buttonright ?? ""}`} size="sm" value={3072} bsPrefix='ia'>{"Thorough"}</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
        </div>
    );
};

Below is my package.json:
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "watch": "tsc && vite build --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.110.7",
    "@fluentui/react-icons": "^2.0.195",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.1",
    "dompurify": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.13.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "nanoid": "3.3.4",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dompurify": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.10",
    "postcss-nesting": "^11.2.2"
  }
}

Am I doing something wrong?

Add the code where Button is used, atleast the import statement.

try npm install @types/react @types/react-dom @types/react-bootstrap

still getting same issue.

I think you should insert import React from 'react' at the first line of the file

not working even with importing react

Possibly related

Returning ReactNode from a React component requires the JSX.ElementType type. Support for ElementType was added in TypeScript 5.1 (release notes). This type was implemented in @types/react 18.2.7.
ReactNode is the correct return type for React components. You need to make sure your dependencies are not too out of date.

Add in Props children: ReactNode

I am very new to react. Do you have any code for that?

interface Props {
  className?: string;
  onClick: (_ev: any) => void;
  defaultValue?: number, 
  children?: ReactNode
}

